# How to update a database using textboxes so when a user clicks 'update' the changes are then implemented

Tags: php, html, ajax, database

I'm quite new to PHP & MySQL and at the minute I have a web page with several text boxes that displays data that is in my database. I would like to know how I would go about updating the data by making changes to the textboxes so that when the user clicks 'update' these changes are then implemented in the database.

Currently I have the following code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("booking", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblcompany");


$compDetails = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

?>

And here is some of the HTML:

```
<div class="cp-controls-lrg left">
    <p class="controls-margin">Company Name</p>
    <input type="text" class="input-txt-med" value="<?php echo $compDetails['CompName'] ?>" id="txt-config-fax" value="" size="20">
</div>

<div class="cp-controls-lrg left">
    <p class="controls-margin">Company URL</p>
    <input type="text" class="input-txt-med button-space2" value="<?php echo $compDetails['CompURL'] ?>" id="txt-config-email" value="" size="50">
</div>

<div class="cp-button2 config-but-space right">
    <button name="btn-config-done" id="btn-config-done" class="btn-sml ui-button ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-all btn-hover-anim btn-row-wrapper right cp-btn-margin">Done</button>
    <button name="btn-config-update" id="btn-config-update" class="btn-sml ui-button ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-all btn-hover-anim btn-row-wrapper right cp-btn-margin">Update</button>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You might look into the `INSERT`and `UPDATE` mysql-statements. Try follow some guides and ask for more concrete help, if you get stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the tag that you want to use AJAX to achieve this.

I would first try to do the update by posting the form back using POST.
Put your HTML code into a `form` tag and try to POST data back to PHP page.

Here's just one example on how to do it (Google/Bing is your friend):

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php

http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/4

Then look up Insert and Update statements as suggested above and try to do the same with your data.

AJAX works in a similar way, there is a processor on the server side and the only difference is that the form doesn't get submitted via POST (page reload) but it's submitted using JavaScript.

I would also look into jQuery library to do the AJAX postbacks for you.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is excellent for ajax. You can use something like this in your javascript file whatever.js.

```
$('#btn-config-update').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://whatever.com/handler.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: {
            companyname : $('#companyFieldID').val(),
            url : $('#companyURLID').val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "Success") {
                $('#id_of_div_to_replace_markup').html(data.markup);
            } else if (data.status == "Error"){
                $('#optional_error_markup_container_div').html(data.markup);
            } else {
                  $('#optional_error_markup_container_div').html("<span id=formError>Unexpected Error</span>");
            }
        }
    });
return false;
});
```

Things to note here.  Use id='whateverid" not class="whateverclass" inside of your input markup fields, so that you can get the data out of the input fields using the .val() statements that you see above.  the # references in jQuery refer to a unique id.

Also the return false prevents the page from refreshing.
now for the PHP side.

```
$sql_error_markup = "<h1>An unexpected error has occured.  Please try again later.</h1>";
$success_markup = "<h2><p>Database has been updated!</p></h2>";

$companyname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["companyname"]);
$url = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["url"]);

//use your connection logic to get $con

$sql="INSERT INTO tablename (company_field_name, url_field_name)";
$sql.= " VALUES('$companyname','$lastname','$email')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
    $return['markup'] = $sql_error_markup;
    $return['status'] = "Error";
    echo json_encode($return);
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($con);
$return['status'] = "Success";
$return['markup'] = $success_markup;
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Things to note echo json_encode(array) will respond to the ajax call properly.  This ajax example can swap out markup using the html method of anything with an id (not class in this example). mysql_real_escape_string will help prevent injection attacks. Extrememly necessary for this sort of form.  Don't forget to include jquery.versionwhatever.js to use the $ references that you see above.

Good luck.